# Why does JCE delete text in an article that looks like an html tag?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-content-editor

I am using a plugin named CodeHighlighter to insert a code snippet inside articles in my Joomla 2.5 website using JCE.

To insert the code snippet, I do the following in JCE:

I swap to the HTML code view and, for example, I insert something like this:

```
<pre class="brush:java">
package com.tutorialspoint;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextStartedEvent;

public class CStartEventHandler 
    implements ApplicationListener<ContextStartedEvent>{

    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextStartedEvent event) {
         System.out.println("ContextStartedEvent Received");
    }
}
</pre>
```

This works well except for this part of code: `<ContextStartedEvent>` which is eliminated by JCE. I have also tried using a no WYSIWIG editor and there is no problem.

So the problem seems to be that JCE sees `<ContextStartedEvent>` as a tag and not as a legal part of my Java code snippet, and so deletes it...

Do you have some idea about how prevent JCE from deleting this part of code?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
1. Go to Global Configuration
2. Click "Text Filters" Tab.
3. Change "Super Users" filter type to "no filtering"
```

This will solve problems such as these.

- Youtube videos wont work in Joomla (code gets deleted)
- JCE TinyMCE code cleanup deletes my styles code and scripts.
- Inline document styles (css) gets removed by JCE or TinyMCE in Joomla
- Code cleanup problems in JCE / TinMCE
- Flash scripts being removed by JCE code cleanup

Comment: I have this problem but still doing this the JCE and also tinyMCE delete attributes like onclick and delete <a> tag wrapping <div> tag. Any idea?

Comment: Does this happen also when you edit the plain html source with TinyMCE?

Comment: Yes, I tried with both editor, but the only way it does not delete tags is disabling any wysiwyg editor. And of course I m logged as super user.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://www.clarica.com.au/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=129:code-cleanup-issues-in-jce-a-tinymce-scripts-removed-etc&catid=10:free-joomla-video-tutorials-training&Itemid=28
or 
https://www.joomla-monster.com/blog/joomla-3-0/how-to-stop-joomla-editor-from-cleaning-some-html-elements

Comment: @DiegoQuirós [joomla.se] Stack Exchange went public as of April 29th, 2014.  Whenever you have a Joomla question, please post it there.